# Can I generate multiple new records based on value in another table, in MS Access 2013?

Tags: ms-access, append, subforms

I'll qualify this with the upfront admission that I am *not* a professional programmer or database designer.  I had a specific problem to solve - the need to manage a great deal of information on employee benefit requests - and limited resources, and built a database to replace the Excel spreadsheet I inherited.  I'm learning as I go, and what I'd really like to find out is, can Access do what I'm envisioning, or do I need to adjust my goal?

The main tables my database includes are EMPLOYEES, REQUESTS, TASKS, and ACTIVITY (plus some auxiliary tables used for drop-down fields, etc.).  Each employee can have multiple requests, and for each request, I used TASKS to keep track of all that needs to be done, by whom and by when, to see the request through from start to finish (I'm the only user of the dbase file itself, but I publish the task list as a report to those involved). ACTIVITY, as you would expect, is the "journaling" feature where I keep track of what's been done, conversations, etc.

What I want to do now is speed up the process of task entry, since for MOST requests, the taskflow is pretty similar.  I already created tables for "TASK OWNER" and "TASK CATEGORIES" - both related to my primary TASKS table - so I could standardize the data entry for those fields, in addition to filtering on it ("show me everything the employee owns").  TASKS has a "NOTES" field so I can individualize the entry without changing the drop-downs.  It's progress, but I'm still spending too much time adding the same however-many tasks to each new request I set up.

What I've been playing with in my head is identifying tasks with some sort of code that associates them with a type of request - i.e., an employee request for tuition reimbursement is identified as "request type 001" and all the tasks that normally go with a tuition reimbursement have a lookup field connecting them back to "001" - so that when I check a box or select "001 - Tuition Reimbursement" from a drop-down on my form, the 6 or 8 "standard" tasks automatically drop in to the TASKS subform, BUT they're NEW records - not just "template tasks" that I'm querying from my TASK CATEGORIES.  I want to be able to tweak, edit, update, and even delete them, without affecting any other request.

I've found a lot of information adding new records via APPEND queries, but it seems to be limited to generating ONE record for each "transaction" if that makes sense - each time the query finds its value and performs the action, one record is generated.  How do I get Access to recognize one value - request type - and generate each of the tasks associated with that request type as a new record in TASKS?

Comment: Yes you can. But to get an actual answer, please read this: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: Thanks, reading now.  Sorry, this could have been much better.  My imagination exceeds my skill set and I'm impatient. :(

Answer (score 0):

User selects category of request, such as 'Tuition Reimbursement' from a multi-column combobox. Hidden column of combobox has the category code and this is the bound column so this is value of combobox. Then code to save multiple records would be like:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Tasks(RequestID, TaskDesc) SELECT " & _ 
     Me.tbxReqID & " AS RID, TaskDesc FROM TasksCategories WHERE TaskCat = " & Me.cbxCategory
```

The real trick is figuring out what event to put this code into. Should it be automatic after some data element is entered or should it be a button click? Then there is need to prevent duplicate entries - what if user accidentally clicks that button again? (This might be handled by a compound index setting in table.) Also, the new master record created on requests form has to be committed to table first. Record is committed when closing table/query/form, moving to another record, or running command to save.

As shown, your requirement is certainly possible, just keep in mind "the more user-friendly, the more code".

Now, when you develop code with specific issue, post it for analysis.